# incremental sync of git repos using bundle

Tags: git

This is a bit of a specific question, which if answered, hopefully may help others who are struggling with this generic set of issues. I have a git repo that my partner has mirrored on his system. There is no central repository, so no pushing.

I want to keep my partner's repo synced with mine whenever possible. The way I have been doing it right now is to do:

```
git bundle create repo.bundle --all
```

My partner is not very well versed in git and may probably never be, so I must do all the heavy lifting. Right now, I access his system desktop remotely, rm the old git repository, clone a new one from the bundle and then checkout all branches to have local refs.

Obviously this is quite tedious and also, transferring an "--all" bundle is getting problematic due to the big size of the bundle which grows with every new commit. I know that it is possible to create an abbreviated bundle of only the changes since the last full repo was bundled, but I can't get either the create or the sync to work right.

My repo tree looks like this (m == master, a == branch a, b == branch b):

```
- m1 - m2 - m3  
             |\
             |  a1
              \
                b1
```

.. etc with a few more branches. Each branch has only one commit extra plus master.

My question: I work on the master branch, add another commit and then rebase all the branches to the master HEAD so my repo then looks like this:

```
-m1 - m2 - m3 - m4
                  |\
                  |  a1'
                   \
                     b1'
```

The different branch commits at the heads of the branches are due to the rebasing merges, as all the subordinate branches track master changes with their own small additions, etc.

How do I formulate first the git bundle to only have M4 and all new branch commits, all branches rebased to M4? And then, is there a simple git pull command or set of commands to update my partner's repository with all of the contents in the bundle correctly? If so, then my partner could execute these commands without my needing to access his system.

Comment: Can't you push and pull from the bundle as if it were a remote?

Comment: yes, as I said, I cannot get the commands to work just right. especially for a partial bundle.. and how do I make that partial bundle based on my figures above?

Comment: You can specify what to exclude `git bundle create repo.bundle ^remote/a1 ^remote/a2 a1 a2` but you will have explicitly name every branch you need.

Comment: That would create a bundle including only stuff on `a1` and `a2` not in the bundle `remote`. From that point you should be able to do a simple `git pull` from the other repository.

Comment: (edited my reply) Thanks for the replies, This is closer to what I am looking for but still missing what is needed. what about master? add ^master/m4 to that command? a1 and a2 have changed, so they are not the same commit. Also, what is "remote"? Right now, my repo has no remote. Also, I did not show that I have more than 2 branches. I have more than a few. Must I enumerate all branches to do this? Basically, I want to get a snapshot of all changes since the tree in the first diagram including all branch changes and rebases without needing to know all branch names. Is this even possible?